# If an Hacker get salt and our hashed password from a database, why can't he hack the password?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, salt

They say salting a password and then hashing it will be far more secure. We all Know that passwords are salted and then hashed, eventually get stored in databases.
During Data breaches a hacker can get password(salted and hashed) along with salt because salt is also stored in the databases for validation purpose.
Then why it is not easy to crack if the hacker can get both salt and password which is salted and hashed?
I thought that after getting the salt a hacker can found what password(salted and hashed) is it and then he can remove the salt from it to get the original password!

consider for example:(this is how I am thinking the things are happening)
my password: Harivignesh123
salt to be added : 1$2$3

my new salted pass could be : Harivignesh1231$2$3

In database:
password(salted and hashed) : 8a84dbd1ab769dfdeaf389a38a91feb7f0a3d9ea5e34254775dd66a5b82a402d
salt: 1$2$3

After hacker got data from data breach:
by some method( may be using hashcat) he found that my password is : Harivignesh1231$2$3
he also know that my salt is(because it is also stored in database): 1$2$3

so he can remove 1$2$3(salt) from the password and yeah he found it right? is it that easy? then how could it be more secure as they say! or salting is just to make sure every password is unique?

Help this newbie to come over this doubt and please point out if I am wrong with my thinking and thank you very much for your explanation in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Because users pick predictable passwords, and there are databases of hashes for likely passwords - NIST quote an entropy figure of 4-bits per character. These databases are called [Rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Using a salt means the attacker needs to compute all the hashes again using the salted value.

Comment: The purpose of salts is indeed resistance to precomputation (making it infeasible). Minor nuance: long before we resort to rainbow tables, we simply use what password crackers call "dictionaries" or "wordlists" - lists of common passwords - in "straight" wordlists attacks. We then move on to other efficient attacks long before rainbow tables (rules, masks, etc). In fact, with modern GPU power, rainbow tables are now only useful in very narrow circumstances (random or unusual passwords of short *known* length, high value target, very low number of hashes). Most hash crackers never use them.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams: Rainbow tables are valuable in exactly the same situations they always were: where pre-computation is possible and the attacker is going after multiple passwords.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk We'll have to let our respective statements stand in lieu of a debate. :D

Answer (score 0):

The "*by some method*" is the crux here, it is not possible to revers a hash to its original password. What hashcat does, is to try millions of possible passwords and check if they result in the stolen hash.

With a long salt (much longer than in your example) it is not possible to precalculate all those hashes in a single rainbow-table, to later get the password quickly. Salted passwords like `Harivignesh123mI82hjHHw1QwertxcvgZP0` would require way too many combinations/time.

Thus by salting, the attacker could build a rainbow-table only after knowing the salt, and then the rainbow-table can be used only for this salt. Because one uses a unique salt for each password, a rainbow-table could find onyl a single password.

If you want to know more about this topic, you can have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: Thanks for Helping me up and yeah I understood the concept from your explanation. @symcbean